# PHP - Some special character is appearing as question mark� while displaying

Tags: php, html, utf-8, special-characters, utf

PHP - Some special character is appearing as question mark�  while displaying.

I have added the utf-8 encoding for both html and php but its not working

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php  
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $output = '';  

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "appsrx1a_skyfler");

     $query = "SELECT * FROM candidate_tabletest where id =      '".$_POST["member_id"]."'"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  


 ?>    
<table class="table table-bordered "> 
        <?php  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {

                <tr>  
                 <td><label>Address</label></td>  
                 <td><?php echo $row["address"];?></td>  
            </tr>  

                </table>
     <?php          
  }
  ?>


 </div>  

 </body>
  </html>
```

In database the content of Address field is :-
"H.No 2 – D, L.C.H, SAIDABADCOLONY, HYDERABAD – 59"
 but in when it echoes the address it shows :-
"H.No 2 � D, L.C.H, SAIDABADCOLONY, HYDERABAD � 59."

I have made some research but i have added the meta tag for utf which were mentioned in many documentation . What might be the solution for this ?

Comment: You never tell MySQL what encoding you want to use.

Comment: am a complete newbie ... Where exactly i have to make the changes ?

Comment: [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php). Surprisingly, it's missing from most examples.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález mysqli_set_charset resolved the issue .. thanks a ton